# Unity Hub constantly keeps asking for the same update, but downgrades after computer restart

Tags: unity-game-engine

Right now, my Unity Hub is version 2.1.2. Every time I start the program up, it asks me for an update to version 2.2.2. Every time I install the update, it does install correctly and the application sticks to that new version until I restart my computer. After a restart, it goes back to version 2.1.2, and Unity Hub asks me for that 2.2.2 update AGAIN.
This has been happenning to me for a few months now. Any idea what the issue might be and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have permissions on your file-system to correctly "save" the updated version onto your disk?
Have you considered starting a discussion on the [Unity Hub section of the Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/forums/unity-hub.142/) ?

Comment: Check eventlog to find out why its not permitting for you to finish the upgrade, or download it directly from unity, remove the currently installed hub, and install the new one.. 2.2.2 has been out a fair while.

Comment: Alright, I believe I'll just install the 2.2.2 directly from the unity website for now. Should I encounter this issue again though, I will also ask this question on the unity forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, all I did was just completely reinstall (uninstall, along with Unity) the Unity Hub, and I didn't run into this issue again. Strange...